# How to check for username and password from hashmap

Tags: java, hashmap, user-input

I am trying to create a small client/server chat application that requires a login. I have made 3 hash maps, 1 for pre-existing users, 1 for admin, and 1 for registering users. I can log in with the pre-existing users, and I can log in with the admin user but I am unable to log in using the details of the users who have been registered. How can I fix this as I have tried a few ways but nothing seems to work?

The registered users go into a hashmap which is in a publicly accessible class and I can add new users to that hashmap but I cannot get the log button to check that hash map.

Class containing map

```
public class map {
    
        public static HashMap<String, String> usermap = new HashMap<>();
        
        public HashMap<String, String> getUsers()
        {
            return usermap;
        }
     }
```

Login Button

```
private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

        String username = userText.getText();
        String password = passwordText.getText();
        Component frame = null;

      //Create a map for users where put username as key and password as value
      Map<String, String> usersMap = new HashMap<>();
      usersMap.put("user1", "password1");
      usersMap.put("user2", "password2");

      //Create a map for the admin where put username as key and password as value
      Map<String, String> adminMap = new HashMap<>();
      adminMap.put("Admin", "password");

      // Implement your authentication
      if(usersMap.get(username) != null){
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "You are successfully logged in!");
           setVisible(false); //you can't see me!
           dispose(); //Destroy the JFrame object
           chatClient second = new chatClient();
           second.setVisible(true); //displays the client page

      } else if (adminMap.get(username) != null){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "You are successfully logged in!");
            setVisible(false); //you can't see me!
            dispose(); //Destroy the JFrame object
            chatServer third = new chatServer();
            third.setVisible(true); //displays the server page

      } else if (map.usermap.equals(username,password)){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "You are successfully logged in!");
            setVisible(false); //you can't see me!
            dispose(); //Destroy the JFrame object
            chatServer third = new chatServer();
            third.setVisible(true); //displays the server page    
      }else {
            success.setText("Invalid username or password entered");
      }    
        
    
    }
```

Comment: You should be getting a syntax error on `map.usermap.equals(username,password)` because there is no `equals` method in `HashMap` that takes 2 arguments. I suspect you want `password.equals(map.usermap.get(username))`.

Comment: I see, Thank you for your help.

Comment: Why create that `map` class just to hold a map instance?

Comment: Other things to consider: you really don't need 3 maps. Better to have a field inside a user class the stores the 'type' of user and then you'll only need 1 map. Also note that `public static` variables (i.e. not `final`) are considered bad practice by just about every experienced Java coder.

Comment: It was one of my requirements for my assignment @BasilBourque

Comment: @sprinter Thanks for letting me know, I'm still a beginner with java just playing with the code to get it to do what I need it too to meet my requirements

Answer (score 2):

As discussed in comments, a clearer way of modelling your problem would be:

```
enum UserType {
    EXISTING, ADMIN, REGISTERING;
}

class User {
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private UserType type;
}
```

Really the only reason to have a map to look up passwords by user name is if you were going to have a lot of users or do the lookup many times each second. If you wanted that map then it would look like:

```
Map<String,User> userMap;
```

And your code would become:

```
if (userMap.contains(username) && userMap.get(username).getPassword().equals(password)) {
    ...
}
```